# Making a swap Sub on pictureboxes with drag/drop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I want to make a dynamic sub that can be applied on my from, I have 3x3 matrix with pictureboxes and I want to change the images in them with each other with the drag/drop style.

I have found this code and I see how it work but I want to make it dynamic so it will work on all of the 9 picboxes I have in the form and not only on the first two.

```
Dim firstimage As Image
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox2.AllowDrop = True
End Sub
Private Sub pictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        PictureBox1.DoDragDrop(PictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.All)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub pictureBox2_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.DragEnter
    firstimage = PictureBox2.Image
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub pictureBox2_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.DragDrop
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap)) Then
        PictureBox2.Image = CType((e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)), Bitmap)
        PictureBox1.Image = firstimage 'Set picturebox1 to the stored image
    End If
End Sub
```

i have read and used the idle_mind answer and its work great thats what i was looking for but i need one more update to for it to work for me.
i need it not only to change the image but also the tag of the boxes(swap them like the image.)
what i did here is what only the first one get the tag but the second one dont can you explane where i need to add the code change.

```
Private Sub PBs_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        If Not IsNothing(PB.Image) AndAlso e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Source = PB
            PB.DoDragDrop(PB.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy Or DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PBs_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
            Else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
            End If
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PBs_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
            Else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
            End If
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PBs_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
        Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        Dim tmpImage As Image = PB.Image
        Dim tmptag As Integer = PB.Tag ` The Tag Temp
        PB.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
        If e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move Then
            If Not (PB Is Source) Then
                Source.Image = tmpImage
                Source.Tag = tmptag ` the first picbox gets the new tag
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I can't understand this, you have the code that works for two picture boxes, but can't extrapolate it to work with 9 picture boxes?

Comment: That code is seriously flawed.  `pictureBox1` is going to start a dragDrop swap fest everytime the mouse **moves**.  Drag is usually thought of as moving the mouse while holding the button down.

Comment: See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27540717/2330053) in this thread.

Comment: Mathemats yes i have this code but its for 2 specific pictureboxes i want it to be for all of the ones i have in the form.  Idle_Mind i saw the code and its great but it is only move or copy i need it to be aswap between the picA and picB and it should work on all of them can you change it for me?

Comment: Read my **entire** answer in that thread.  There is code in there to **swap** them as well...

Comment: i have an update on my question if you take a look on it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Drop, you correctly stored the Tag from the Target in a temp variable, but only set the Tag in the Source, not the Target as well (you did half a swap).

So you're missing `PB.Tag = Source.Tag`.

Change it to:

```
Private Sub PBs_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
    Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim tmpImage As Image = PB.Image
    Dim tmptag As Integer = PB.Tag ` The Tag Temp
    PB.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
    PB.Tag = Source.Tag
    If e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move Then
        If Not (PB Is Source) Then
            Source.Image = tmpImage
            Source.Tag = tmptag ` the first picbox gets the new tag
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically attach event to all your picturebox.

See this example

```
Public Class Form1


    Dim firstimage As Image
    Dim pold As PictureBox
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.AllowDrop = True
        PictureBox2.AllowDrop = True
        PictureBox3.AllowDrop = True
        PictureBox4.AllowDrop = True
        PictureBox5.AllowDrop = True
        AddHandler PictureBox1.MouseMove, AddressOf p_MouseMove
        AddHandler PictureBox1.DragEnter, AddressOf p_DragEnter
        AddHandler PictureBox1.DragDrop, AddressOf p_DragDrop
        AddHandler PictureBox1.MouseEnter, AddressOf P_MouseEnter

        AddHandler PictureBox2.MouseMove, AddressOf p_MouseMove
        AddHandler PictureBox2.DragEnter, AddressOf p_DragEnter
        AddHandler PictureBox2.DragDrop, AddressOf p_DragDrop
        AddHandler PictureBox2.MouseEnter, AddressOf P_MouseEnter

        AddHandler PictureBox3.MouseMove, AddressOf p_MouseMove
        AddHandler PictureBox3.DragEnter, AddressOf p_DragEnter
        AddHandler PictureBox3.DragDrop, AddressOf p_DragDrop
        AddHandler PictureBox3.MouseEnter, AddressOf P_MouseEnter

        AddHandler PictureBox4.MouseMove, AddressOf p_MouseMove
        AddHandler PictureBox4.DragEnter, AddressOf p_DragEnter
        AddHandler PictureBox4.DragDrop, AddressOf p_DragDrop
        AddHandler PictureBox4.MouseEnter, AddressOf P_MouseEnter

        AddHandler PictureBox5.MouseMove, AddressOf p_MouseMove
        AddHandler PictureBox5.DragEnter, AddressOf p_DragEnter
        AddHandler PictureBox5.DragDrop, AddressOf p_DragDrop
        AddHandler PictureBox5.MouseEnter, AddressOf P_MouseEnter
    End Sub

    Private Sub P_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim p As PictureBox = sender
        pold = p
        Me.Text = pold.Name
    End Sub
    Private Sub p_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dim p As PictureBox = sender
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            p.DoDragDrop(p.Image, DragDropEffects.All)

        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub p_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)
        Dim p As PictureBox = sender
        firstimage = p.Image
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub p_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)
        Dim p As PictureBox = sender
        If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap)) Then
            p.Image = CType((e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)), Bitmap)
            pold.Image = firstimage 'Set picturebox1 to the stored image
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Just add as many picturebox you want and attach 4 different event handler to it.